# Search results into listbox?

Tags: html, vb.net, search, listbox

This is my first post on here. I used this site before and finally decided to make an account.

I am trying to make a program which lists the `url's` of the first 50 sites a Google search turns up. I am a beginner in VB.net, I know I should try something easier, but I really wanna make this program.

My idea how to accomplish this was to get the HTML and then get the links to the sites from there, but when I looked at the HTML of the Google search results page, most of the links weren't there. So, I right clicked one of the results and found that the `url's` can be found between the `<cite>` tags.

[image]

My question is:
How do I get the HTML from each element into a string?

Comment: You should really consider installing [HTMLAgilityPack](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to ease the process of parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) can considerably ease the process of parsing HTML.

Here's a very basic implementation to do what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub DoSearch(query As String)
    Dim wc = New WebClient()
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://google.com/search?q=" + query))
    AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf ParseResults
End Sub

Private Sub ParseResults(sender As Object, e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    LvResults.Items.Clear()

    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(e.Result)

    For Each node In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='r']/a")
        Dim item As New ListViewItem(node.InnerText)
        item.SubItems.Add(CleanURL(node.Attributes("href").Value))
        LvResults.Items.Add(item)
    Next

    LvResults.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
End Sub

Private Function CleanURL(url As String) As String
    url = url.Replace("/url?q=", "")
    If url.Contains("&") Then url = url.Split("&"c)(0)
    Return url
End Function
```

The trick to successfully using the HTML Agility Pack is to know the correct XPath that will generate the correct results, but this can be tricky, specially for first time users.

So, I highly recommend you that you download [HAP Testbed](http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/) to help you test and experiment with multiple XPaths until you get exactly what you are looking for (without having to continuously debug your application to test your changes).

---

If you wish, you can download a functional sample that implements this code: [SearchToListView](http://software.xfx.net/stackoverflow/SearchToListView.zip)

Comment: you rock ! it worked exactly how i wanted it to work. thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are only concerned with extracting what is between `<cite>` and `</cite>`, you can parse the string by splitting on `<cite>` then removing `</cite>` from each item. You could also remove the `<b>` and `</b>` from each item. Items from index 1 to the upper bound of the array should have your links.